# How do I install the Python readchar package in Anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda, installation

I have a Python 3 script that I am trying to run via the Anaconda prompt in Windows 10, but Anaconda can't find the readchar module(package) to import.

When I run the script from the Anaconda prompt I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\SPTProgrammer\Start.py", line 7, in <module>
    from readchar import readkey as _readkey
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'readchar'
```

I tried to install it using: conda install readchar, but I get this message:

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

- readchar

I went to anaconda.org to search for another "channel" to get readchar, but it wasn't found their either.

I next tried pip install readchar --user, that seemed to work, but I still get the same ModuleNotFoundError in Anaconda prompt. I am guessing this installed the module for use with Visual Studio 2017, but not Anaconda.

I am new to using Anaconda, and not that experienced in Python. It seems the readchar package is available, I just need help figuring out how to get installed in Anaconda.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Steve

Comment: use pip, it'll probably be fine. #yolo

Comment: activate your env `conda activate <your-env>` and then install the package using `pip install readchar`. This is working for me.